# Prevent message to be saved on Sent Items folder

Tags: vb.net, system.net.mail

My Office 365 Sent Items folder is plenty of copies of the messages my website sends upon visitors requests.
I wonder if System.Net.Mail.MailMessage has any option to prevent the message to save a copy in the Sent Items folder, something like the "Do Not Save" feature of Outlook.

This is my email code (commented my request):

```
Private Sub SendSimpleMail(MailServerUrl As String, username As String, password As String, From As String, [to] As String, subject As String, body As String)
    Dim oSmtpClient As SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(MailServerUrl)
    oSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    oSmtpClient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password)

    Dim oMessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(From, [to])
    oMessage.Subject = subject
    oMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    oMessage.Body = body
    oMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    oMessage.IsBodyHtml = True

    ' oMessage.DoNotSave = true 

    oSmtpClient.Send(oMessage)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a .DeleteAfterSubmit property on the message.  If so set it to True.

Comment: A pity there is none. This property is only exposed by VBA Outlook mailItem object

Comment: fi server is an Exchange server you might be able to use MailItem instead.